# json pointers not resolved in python module

Tags: python, json, pointers

I have created a json file that has some values in a central area and then a sub area that uses pointers to get values from the central area. I am trying to load the json using the `json` module from python but when I load the file it doesn't resolve the pointers to the desired values but rather acts as it they are just more text. How can I make it work to resolve pointers when they are there along with also working when there are no pointers?

Code:

```py
import json
data = json.loads(open("test.json").read())
print(data)

#Output:
#{'ColoringLight': {'bg': '#ffffff', 'fg': '#4f4c4d', 'TokenText': '#544619', 'TokenKeyword': '#2f33ff', 'TokenPunctuation': '#dd8ced', 'TokenName': '#b6c23f', 'TokenOperator': '#f6a656', 'TokenComment': '#2cbe48', 'TokenLiteralNumber': '#ab4bbe', 'TokenLiteralString': '#f45159'}, 'syntax': {'Token.Text': {'$ref': '#/ColoringLight/TokenText'}, 'Token.Keyword': {'$ref': '#/ColoringLight/TokenKeyword'}, 'Token.Punctuation': {'$ref': '#/ColoringLight/TokenPunctuation'}, 'Token.Name.Attribute': {'$ref': '#/ColoringLight/TokenName'}, 'Token.Operator': {'$ref': '#/ColoringLight/TokenOperator'}, 'Token.Comment': {'$ref': '#/ColoringLight/TokenComment'}, 'Token.Literal.Number.Bin': {'$ref': '#/ColoringLight/TokenLiteralNumber'}, 'Token.Literal.String.Affix': {'$ref': '#/ColoringLight/TokenLiteralString'}}}
```

test.json:

```json
{
    "ColoringLight":
    {
        "bg": "#ffffff",
        "fg": "#4f4c4d",
        "TokenText": "#544619",
        "TokenKeyword": "#2f33ff",
        "TokenPunctuation": "#dd8ced",
        "TokenName": "#b6c23f",
        "TokenOperator": "#f6a656",
        "TokenComment": "#2cbe48",
        "TokenLiteralNumber": "#ab4bbe",
        "TokenLiteralString": "#f45159"
    },

    

    "syntax":
    {
        "Token.Text": {"$ref": "#/ColoringLight/TokenText"},
        "Token.Keyword": {"$ref": "#/ColoringLight/TokenKeyword"},
        "Token.Punctuation": {"$ref": "#/ColoringLight/TokenPunctuation"},
        "Token.Name.Attribute": {"$ref": "#/ColoringLight/TokenName"},
        "Token.Operator": {"$ref": "#/ColoringLight/TokenOperator"},
        "Token.Comment": {"$ref": "#/ColoringLight/TokenComment"},
        "Token.Literal.Number.Bin": {"$ref": "#/ColoringLight/TokenLiteralNumber"},
        "Token.Literal.String.Affix": {"$ref": "#/ColoringLight/TokenLiteralString"}

    }
}
```

NOTE:

As pointed out after posting it turns out that json has no pointers built in

Comment: json doesn't have pointers. The code that generated this would not have been the default `json` library. Instead, it would have been a third-party library that adds pointer capability. Since pointers aren't part of the spec, and so can be implemented however, you may need to figure out which specific library was used to create your content.

Comment: `json` has no concept of pointers. You will have to parse the `dict` that `json.loads()` returns and parse these strings and transform them into what you want.

Comment: Understood. Thank you for pointing that out. I had found pointers [here](https://json-spec.readthedocs.io/reference.html) and since it seemed to be json docs I assumed it was built in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON references are not part of the JSON specification, but an extension. You could install a library like [jsonref](https://pypi.org/project/jsonref/), then you could do:

```
import jsonref
data = jsonref.loads(open("test.json").read())
print(data)
```